# Gradient color is not working on button Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I added customized gradient color in my project but it's not working.

Colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#9C27B0</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#7B1FA2</color>
    <color name="pink_500">#FF1493</color>
    <color name="black_100">#000000</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<!--    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>-->
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="darker_gray">#A9A9A9</color>


</resources>
```

Themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Opus" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

My customized input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/purple_200" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/darker_gray" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

I tried changing colorPrimary to @null in theme file but then my app is crashing/not opening. I am new to this, so I dont know how colorPrimary is linked with other files as well, where else I need to make changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to design a custom button in android studio, but it isn't getting applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70506249/i-am-trying-to-design-a-custom-button-in-android-studio-but-it-isnt-getting-ap)

Answer (score 0):

Probably I think you might be using button component in Android XML you might use

Instead of

Use
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).